# how to get git and gpg working together again

Tags: git, github, gnupg

I'm trying to revive a project I've been ignoring for about a decade, and find that my tools are not working.  I'm on Xubuntu 20.04, all software up-to-date.  When I try to make a new git commit, it fails with a complaint about gpg.  In fact, if I start a new git repository, the first commit fails, so it's not a problem in the data I'm committing, but my configuration is messed up.

The message is always the same:

```
me@here$ git commit -a
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
me@here$
```

When I ask it to, gpg lists a single RSA key, attributed to one of my emails, dated last year.  I created it when I learned GitHub was phasing out passwords, but I'm not sure I
ever used it.

Other symptoms

- when I attempt gpg --sign (with something in stdin) I get a popup dialog asking me for a passphrase.  I have no recollection of that, and I did not make any note of such a thing in the place I would normally do that.

So the questions are:

- what else can I do to figure out exactly what is broken
- how can I fix it

Comment: Can you run `gpg --sign` on its own? Does that work? What do you have configured in git for `user.signingkey`? Does it match the RSA key in your keyring?

Comment: @Useless I edited the question to reflect the popup and request for a passphrase.  I have no idea how to look at user.signingkey.

Comment: Have a look at the [git GPG documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work) and you'll see how the signing key is _set_. To see the value, just run `git config user.signingkey`.

Comment: And if you can't sign something using the key directly, it seems like you forgot your private key's passphrase. You will have been prompted to enter one when you created the key, unless you used `--passphrase ''` to omit it explicitly.

Comment: It turns out I had never set up a signingkey.  I was able to tell git about one that GPG knew about, but when I try to use it, GPG wants a passphrase, which I do not know.  I'm suspecting I should reset the signingkey in git and gpg, but the docs I see don't look like what I'm seeing, so I suppose things have changed.  I could use some modern help.